# Sorting output across multiple lines - python

Tags: python, sorting

I have output structured as follows:

```
0 2
4 1
0 3
5 4
3 2
```

From code:

```
 for entry in file:
    a = entry.replace('\n',"")
    b = a.replace(','," ")
    b = b.split(" ")
    print b
```

I was wondering if there is a way to sort(smallest to largest) output across multiple lines, to receive the output as follows:

```
0 2
0 3
1 4
2 3
4 5
```

Comment: How do you generate this output? Can you share your code?

Comment: Edited, it has been drawn from a text file. Note I know how to sort across the row, just not across multiple rows.

Comment: When you say: "I know how to sort across the row, just not across multiple rows", you mean that you can sort by first but not by secondary row?

Comment: I mean that I can sort the entries in the row by smallest to largest, but not the entries in the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming "f" containing the file you showed above, this does the job

```
from operator import itemgetter
with open("f") as f:
    pairs = [line.split(" ") for line in f.readlines()]
    asc_pairs = [(min([int(x),int(y)]), max([int(x), int(y)])) 
            for x,y in pairs]
    print "\n".join([" ".join([str(l) for l in k]) 
        for k in sorted(asc_pairs, key=itemgetter(0,1))])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to store the input in the form of a 2-dimensional array :

```
>>> input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')
>>> lines = input_file.readlines()
>>> lines = map(lambda line : line.strip().split(" "), lines)
>>> lines 
[['0', '2'], ['4', '1'], ['0', '3'], ['5', '4'], ['3', '2']]
```

Now, you need to sort the individual lines first.

```
>>> lines = [sorted(line) for line in lines]
```

Then you can use `sort()` to sort the lines themselves based on a key, in this case: the first element:

```
>>> lines.sort(key = lambda line : line[0])
>>> lines 
[['0', '2'], ['0', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['2', '3'], ['4', '5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

with python you can compare `String` types  with the "greater than and/or less than" `< || >`
taking in place that  letters from a-z or A-Z  the   `n-1` character will allways be `LESS THAN` the `n` character,   so  I think it should work also with numbers as `Strings` so:

```
 for entry in file:
    a = entry.replace('\n',"")
    b = a.replace(','," ")
    b = b.split(" ")
    print  b[0] if b[-1] > b[0] else b[-1]
```